# Div display based on menu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that I want to coorispond with an associated Div.  I have been able to make this function work great with a radio selection.  However, if possible, I would like for it to work based on a menu selection.  The behavior is in the radio buttons labeled "Yes" , "No", and "Maybe" in the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/L5qfn/46/

I would like the same behavior for the menu selection.  I have added a simple menu in the fiddle for working purposes.  Any suggestions?

Comment: By "menu" do you mean a dropdown/<select> tag?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by "menu" you meant dropdown menu. You can use the `change` event for the `select` elements with exactly the same method you used for radio buttons:

```
$('select#answer').change(function() {
    $('div .sub-formset').slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("slow"); //Slide Down Effect
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/L5qfn/47/.

Comment: ahh... he probably does mean a dropdown :)